# Julia - get real part of complex array

Tags: arrays, julia

I need to split the variable `z::Array{Complex128,1}` into two arrays for the real and complex parts.  One way do this is to make new variables `::Array{Float64,1}` and fill them element by element:

```
for i = 1:size(z)[1]
    ri[i] = z[i].re
    ii[i] = z[i].im
end
```

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve copying data, like somehow manipulating strides and offsets of `z`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the common case where copying is not an issue, just do `real.(z)` and `imag.(z)`. I include this to help future readers who have a similar issue, but who might not care about copying.

As you suggest, you can manipulate strides of `z` to avoid copying data. Simply

```
zfl = reinterpret(Float64, z)
zre = @view zfl[1:2:end-1]
zim = @view zfl[2:2:end]
```

Combined, we observe that there is no data copying (the allocations are due to the heap-allocated array views, and are minimal).

```
julia> z = Vector{ComplexF64}(100000);

julia> function reimvec(z)
           zfl = reinterpret(Float64, z)
           zre = @view zfl[1:2:end-1]
           zim = @view zfl[2:2:end]
           zre, zim
       end
reimvec (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time reimvec(z);
  0.000005 seconds (9 allocations: 400 bytes)
```

As we can see, behind the scenes, such an array is strided:

```
julia> strides(reimvec(z)[1])
(2,)
```

Comment: I should mention that unless your arrays are very big or this is occurring in a very tight loop, this is unlikely to save you too much time – copying data is very fast on modern CPUs. But there could be a use case :)

Comment: You can get *marginally* fewer allocations by dropping the `reshape` operation, and just returning `view(a, 1:2:N), view(a, 2:2:N)`. It also makes the code a tiny bit cleaner. You can save a whooping 64 bytes :D

Comment: @DNF Thanks! Updated.

Comment: On the other hand: if your input array is *not* a vector, but a multidimensional array, I don't see how you can avoid `reshape`...

Comment: @DNF I believe `reintepret` accepts a third argument specifying the shape.

Comment: Yes, I (re-)discovered that just a little while ago. It seems undocumented(!) You can use that on the input array, but I think you must reshape the outputs too, and then I you need `reshape`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  Two questions:  `real(z)` and `real.(z)` both work, but `real(z)` returns an `Array{Float64}`, while `real.(z)` returns an `Array{Number}` when `z` is `Array{Complex}`.  When `z` is `Array{Complex128}`, both return `Array{Float64}`.  What is the difference?  Also, my question specified a 1D array, but I just realized I will need a solution for arbitrary shapes.

Comment: Although your array is typed `Array{Complex}`, it happens to contain `Complex128` only, so `real` is able to return the correct type. `real.(x)` is `broadcast(real, x)`, and `broadcast` currently relies on bad machinery instead of using the actual type. In v0.6, `real.(x)` will probably be fixed. For arbitrary shapes, just `reshape` the result here to the shape you like.